# May not call a native

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, bouncycastle

I have created a jar of `cldc_bccore_classes.zip` (bouncy castle light weight api) and preverified it.

I am using this jar in my `Blackberry project`.

Everything worked fine, the jar is preverified and the project runs fine on the simulator.

But when I sign the project and deploy it on the device it gives me an error message :

```
Error starting <AppName>: <AppName> may not call a native method.
```

I have been searching on internet for a long and tried every possible way but not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: i dont know if u've already tried it..but if u haven't..u can give it a try..[Tutorial: How To Use 3rd Party Libraries in your Applications](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Tutorial-How-To-Use-3rd-Party-Libraries-in-your-Applications/td-p/177543;jsessionid=FC3AE3B2ADCF4D66D6795AA4F675C82D)

Comment: I've found this in google: https://www.java.net//node/700008

Comment: Have u found any solution ? I am also facing the same problem